# MVC ScriptBundle CDN version regular and min versions of AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, cdn, minify

From what I have read, I know that MVC bundles can "smartly" include the correct js file (minified or regular) based on whether you are debugging or not. Ideally, I'd like it to load the standard AngularJS when I'm debugging, and the minified version when I am not.

I have the following in my BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.js")
           .Include(~/Scripts/angular.js"));
```

and in my view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
}
```

It doesn't seem to work unless I add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to BundleConfig.cs, but I am skeptical of this. Is this OK to leave in for development AND production? Is this forcing it to always use the regular or minified version in all cases, as opposed to smartly switching like I want? From what I can tell, it appears to be using the non-minified version regardless of whether I am running with the debugger or not, or in release configuration or not.

The other option seemed to be setting debug=false in the web.config, but this prevents me from debugging without manually modifying the file, and I'd like it to be handled automatically if possible.

Then I noticed that MVC uses a `*` syntax for jquery, which happens to have normal and minified versions included:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

So I tried `.Include(~/Scripts/angular*"));` thinking it was a wildcard that would include `.js` or `.min.js` as appropriate but that didn't seem to work either.

Should I be doing something differently?

Comment: Did you turn off debug in your web.config? <compilation debug="false"  />

Comment: Yes I tried this, as stated in the post. But if I do this I am not able to debug. EDIT: to clarify, I get a message from VS saying that I must either change the file, or use ctrl+f5 to start without debugging. I'd really prefer to have this setup where the correct js file is used both when I am debugging and when I am not without having to manually edit anything.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I didn't notice that you stated it in the post.

Comment: (I guess I can't edit a comment after I've already edited it once...?) When I say VS says I must change the file, I mean if offers to revert the file back to `debug=true`.